# Problem with the attribute table values, they are replaced with ************

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-table, values

I suddenly have a problem with my attribute table. When I change a value the whole line is messed up because values shift and the value I add is replaced by ***********. How can I avoid this from happening?

Comment: Wild guess: have you tried changing the width of that column? Some spreadsheets/etc use *s to mean the data is too wide for the column.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't thinks thats the problem. I've used words longer than the one i tried in the same column. It happens with any change...

Comment: When you query a feature (little i tool) as opposed to looking at the table, what is returned?

Comment: Sorry i already threw it away and made a new layer. But when I categorized it in layer styles the stars and all sorts of strange new categories because of the shifting appeared.